# Given a vector c(a1, a2, a3), how to generate c(a1, a2, a3, a2, a3, a3) in R?

Tags: r, matrix

The question has been explained by the title. In my problem, the vector is quite long, approximately 1,500.
One way I was trying is to generate matrix as follows,

[image]

Roughly speaking, this matrix `rbind` three diagonal matrices, `diag(1, 3)`, `diag(1,2)` and `diag(1,1)`. But these matrices have different number of columns. Hence `rbind` does not apply here.  Is there any efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vec <- 1:4
n <- length(vec)
as.vector(rev(setNames(vec, n:1)[as.character(sequence(1:n))]))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4
```

A couple of tricks here; `as.vector` is unnecessary, it just omits vector names.

```
Tyler <- function() do.call(rbind, mapply(compile, rows, nums, lst))
Julius <- function() as.vector(rev(setNames(vec, n:1)[as.character(sequence(1:n))]))

# Vector of length 3
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
#   Tyler() 144.183 148.383 151.649 155.382 2241.617  1000
#  Julius()  73.724  76.058  80.724  82.590  276.236  1000

# Vector of length 1500
# Unit: seconds
#      expr    min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  Julius() 1.2181 1.270544 1.469416 1.506019 1.518471    10
# (list of 1500 diagonal matrices took too much memory, couldn't compare)
```

**Edit.**

```
JuliusTwo <- function() rev(vec[n + 1 - sequence(1:n)])

vec <- 1:3
n <- length(vec)
microbenchmark(Julius(), JuliusTwo(), times = 1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#         expr    min     lq median     uq      max neval
#     Julius() 72.326 75.125 76.525 78.392  259.905  1000
#  JuliusTwo() 49.461 51.794 53.194 54.595 1950.450  1000

vec <- 1:1500
n <- length(vec)
microbenchmark(Julius(), JuliusTwo(), Henrik(x2), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr       min        lq   median        uq       max neval
#     Julius() 1497.9588 1499.9438 1547.660 1582.0843 1590.2048    10
#  JuliusTwo()  157.0313  157.9193  177.682  200.7433  214.9415    10
#   Henrik(x2) 4639.1891 6157.247 7178.9953 7350.8146 7640.8685    10

Matthew <- function() {m <- matrix(rep(vec, n), n);m[lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)]}
microbenchmark(JuliusTwo(), Matthew(), Arun(vec), times = 100)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  JuliusTwo() 113.25630 121.69106 126.16566 150.42730 237.51304   100
#    Matthew() 119.59806 126.87538 152.28000 157.42816 415.27231   100
#    Arun(vec)  32.93695  37.78204  40.99725  43.19757  98.69791   100
```

Comment: Very nice.  I was thinking constructing a simple triplet may also work pretty fast but this seems to do the trick quickly +1

Comment: @Julius +1. Also, try this: `Arun <- function(x) x[sequence(n:1) + rep.int(0:(n-1), n:1)]`

Comment: @Arun, very nice, was thinking about improving my solution in this direction, but didn't expect such an improvement.

Comment: @Julius, me neither :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this pretty simply with `lower.tri`.

```
vec <- 1:4
m <- matrix(rep(vec, length(vec)), length(vec))
m[lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 4
```

This a little bit slower than @Julius' clever answer. See his for benchmarks.

Comment: It should probably be `matrix(rep(vec, length(vec)), length(vec))`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about efficient but here's the solution I used:

```
lst <- list( 
    diag(1, 3),
    diag(1,2) ,
    diag(1,1)
)

cols <- sapply(lst, ncol)
mcol <- max(cols)
rows <- sapply(lst, nrow)
nums <- (mcol - cols)*rows


compile <- function(x, y, z) {
    if (y == 0) return(z)
    cbind(matrix(rep(0, y), nrow = x), z)
}

do.call(rbind, mapply(compile, rows, nums, lst))

#'      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#' [1,]    1    0    0
#' [2,]    0    1    0
#' [3,]    0    0    1
#' [4,]    0    1    0
#' [5,]    0    0    1
#' [6,]    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Several nice solutions already. Still, I give it a try with a `zoo` alternative:

```
library(zoo) 

# the vector
x1 <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
n <- length(x1)

# convert to zoo object
x2 <- zoo(x1)

# lag the vector with a vector of lags
x3 <- lag(x2, k = seq(from = 0, by = 1, length.out = n))

# convert back to vector
na.omit(as.vector(x3))
# [1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a2" "a3" "a3"
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that `k` in `lag` works with vectors as well.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative solution

```
seq_generator=function(vec) if (length(vec)-1>0) c(vec,seq_generator(vec[-1])) else tail(vec,1)
seq_generator(1:4)
```

Comment: maybe not efficient due to recursion

Comment: Jupp! Just checked it: Is relatively slow for larger vectors. Call stack gets probably too large. :) Up to lengths of 500 it's ok, however...